# SVN access from local and remote computers with Visual Studio plug-ins

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control

I'm new to the Version Control topic. I have a few computers on my home network and a remote computer, each having Visual Studio installed. I want to set up SVN server running on one of my local computers; then I want to get access to repository from all the local computers and remote one with Visual Studio plug-ins such as [VisualSvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/). Can this be done (concerned about remote machine) ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done providing that you have connectivity and firewall clearance between the remote and your network.  You can either port forward through your router to your SVN server, and access remotely in VisualSVN using the external IP address, or setup a VPN link to your network and access remotely through that.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use *Subversion* in file repository mode. Basically this lets you create a repository in a LAN folder location.

This mode lets other SVN clients connect to the shared LAN repository.

This is the repositroy mode I use with the Agent SVN Visual Studio plug-in and it works well.